# MS Access sort (comparing string data)

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, ms-access, oledb

I have a .NET application that use MS Access as a database. 
The application worked OK and still works on my PC. But after reinstalling the Windows on client PC, the Application started to work in a very strange way.

In the database the data is in Cyrillic (Macedonian). 
The problem is that the database does not sort strings correctly.

For example, if i run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM exampletbl ORDER BY title
```

The expected results should be:

```
id  title
1   Александар
2   Бранко
3   Влатко
4   Гоце
5   Гвозден
6   Дарко
7   Ѓоре
8   Ѓурѓа
```

...

And currently the access it sorts in this way:

```
id  title
1   Александар
2   Бранко
3   Влатко
4   Гоце
5   Ѓоре
6   Гвозден
7   Ѓурѓа
8   Дарко
```

...

My guess is that region settings or OLE DB driver are not configured propertly  on a client PC and that access is sorting the data as Latin letters.

p.s. The client windows version is Windows 7 x86

Comment: Can you set the collation of access tables?

Comment: I know how to set the collation on MySQL but I don't have big experience in MS Access and i don't know how to set the collation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Change the sort order (on a new database) go to File > Options > General > Creating Databases> New Database Sort Order.

[image]

This will give you

[image]

To have that change take effect in the current database perform a Compact and Repair. That will create a new database in the background (Thanks Gord Thompson for the suggestion)

Comment: *"I'm not sure how to change it for an existing database yet."* - Doing a Compact and Repair Database will implement the change since it creates a "new database" in the process.

Comment: @GordThompson oh nice! That makes sense